# Does $\int_0^t \Vert u_x(s,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2} ds \le C$ imply $\Vert u_x (t,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)} \le C$ in the heat equation?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, parabolic-pde

For the parabolic equation
$$u_t   + f(u)_x - u_{xx} = 0$$
one has
$$\Vert u(t,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)} + 2\int_0^t \Vert u_x(s,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2} ds \le \Vert u(0,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)}.$$
If $t \le T$ (for a fixed $T>0$), does the estimate above imply also $$\Vert u_x (t,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R)} \le C$$
(without time integration)?

In other words, one can also ask: if $\int_0^T f(s) ds \le C$ is it true that $f(t) \le C$ for all $t \in [0,T]$?

Comment: Sending $t \to 0$, this would imply that boundedness of $u(0)$ in $L^2$ would imply boundedness of $u_x(0)$ in $L^2$, which is certainly not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of linear heat equation, we write
$$ u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \Gamma(x-y,t) u_0(y) dy.$$
Here $\Gamma(x,t)$ is the standard heat kernel. Note that
$$ \left|\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^k \Gamma(x,t) \right| \leq C_k t^{-1/2-k/2} \exp \left( -C |x|^2/t\right) $$
for some constant $C>0$.

Hence by Young's convolution inequality, we have
$$ \Vert\nabla u(\cdot,t) \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\leq \Vert{\nabla \Gamma(\cdot,t)}\Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\Vert{u_0}\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})}. $$
A change of variable shows that
$$ \Vert{\nabla \Gamma(\cdot,t)}\Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} \leq C t^{-1/2}$$
for some constant $C>0$.

Hence we get
$$ \Vert\nabla u(\cdot,t) \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\leq C t^{-1/2}\Vert{u_0}\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})} $$
for all $t>0$.

From this point of view, I think that we cannot expect uniform bound in time.